# Close SSE connection Manually : Angular

Tags: angular, server-sent-events

I am using SSE events in my application. For that I have written code which works just fine.

Problem I am facing is I need to close connection after certain time manually let say on some user action. I am not getting any option to do so.

eventSource.close() is there but its in service and unsubscribing it in component doesn't work.

Here goes my code:

***** service.ts*****

```
public getServerSentEventsForTokenDisplay(url: string): Observable<any> {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        const eventSource: EventSourcePolyfill = this.getEventSource(url);
  
        
        eventSource.addEventListener('XXX', (event: any) => {
          observer.next(event);
        });
  
        eventSource.addEventListener('YYY', (event: any) => {
          observer.next(event);
        });
        eventSource.addEventListener('Ack', (event: any) => {
          observer.next(event);
        });
        eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
          eventSource.close()
          this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(error));
        };
        eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(event));
        };
      });
    }
```

**** component.ts *****
`

```
private getTokenDisplay(url) {
    let url = url;

    this.isWaitingTokensLoading = true;
    this.isTokenDisplayLoading = true;
    this.tokenDisplaySubscription = this.qmsService.getServerSentEventsForTokenDisplay(url).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe((response: MessageEvent) => {
      if (response && response.type === 'open') {
        console.log(response)
      }
      if (response && response.type.toLowerCase() === 'ack') {
        console.log(response)
      }
      if (response && response.type === 'XXX') {JSON.parse(response.data));
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(response.data);
        this.tokenDisplayList = parsedData.data;
        this.isTokenDisplayLoading = false;
      }

      if (response && response.type === 'YYY') {
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(response.data);
        this.waitingTokens = parsedData.data;
        this.isWaitingTokensLoading = false;
      }

      if (response && response.type === 'error') {
        console.log(response);
      }
    }, (error) => {
      this.isWaitingTokensLoading = false;
      this.isTokenDisplayLoading = false;
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
    if(this.tokenDisplaySubscription)
    this.tokenDisplaySubscription.unsubscribe();
  }`
```

I need to close SSE connection manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by not using the deprecated `Observable.create` method anymore, but the `Observable` constructor itself. [The recommended way](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#disposing-observable-executions) to dispose of the resources that are used by an observable whenever they are not needed anymore (the observable has no more subscribers) is to return a function in which you can clean up. Something like this:

```js
return new Observable(observer => {
  const eventSource: EventSourcePolyfill = this.getEventSource(url);

    
  eventSource.addEventListener('Token-Display', (event: any) => {
    observer.next(event);
  });

  eventSource.addEventListener('Token-Waiting', (event: any) => {
    observer.next(event);
  });
  eventSource.addEventListener('Ack', (event: any) => {
    observer.next(event);
  });
  eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
    eventSource.close()
    this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(error));
  };
  eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(event));
  };

  return () => {
    console.log('Closing event source...');
    eventSource.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: How to call close in this scenario...?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this question? There is a function, that gets returned at the end. That function is called whenever the observable will have no more subscribers. That's where we call `eventSource.close()`.

Comment: I need to close connection on some action let say on route change or browser closed from some other method in my component code @Octavian

Comment: Will this method automatically called..?

Comment: It will be automatically called whenever you unsubscribe. You already do that inside `ngOnDestroy`. You can also introduce a log there just to see it.

Comment: Yes on unsubscribe() its getting called.

Comment: One more issue I am facing both token-waiting and token-display event is not received at the first time. after refreshing i get both the events. Anything I am missing here. But when I hit curl in my terminal I get both the events i.e. token-display and token-waiting. but this doesnot happen in angular application .

I tried this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(event)); but this is making the events triggered twice